# Rate Monotonic First Fit vs. Rate Monotonic Next Fit vs. Proportionate Fair

Tags: runtime-analysis, parallel-computing, scheduling, real-time, multi-tasking

What would an example of a set of tasks be, where RMFF, RMNF and P-Fair all result in a different number of processors required?

Comment: Hello! We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your exercise for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at it this way.

RMFF- Places Task one after the other until the processor goes beyond the bound

RMNF - Looks at all the processors and see where the task will fit

P-Fair - Uses max utilization of 1 for each processor.

RM can only use N(2^(1/N)-1), this means that both RM will have a different value than P-Fair when utilization is between that value and its upper bound.

As for the RMFF, RMNF just think about it and play with the numbers and you will find answer. Make up task and start placing them according to both methods.

P.S: 2 more hours? Hope it helped.

Comment: You are amazing! This response was beautiful! 

Comment: @JollyGr33nGiant Mark is as an answer if it helped? :)